# Django project and application data model

Tags: django, django-models

I have to build several web-panels and I'm using django. Each panel is a Django Application, so I have:

```
datalake_backend
    __init__.py
    models.py 
    :
    IAV_PANEL
        __init__.py
        models.py
        :
    AMAZON_FUSE_PANEL
        __init__.py
        models.py
        :
```

Currently the command:

```
 ./manage.py makemigrations
```

skips the models defined into

```
 datalake_backend/models.py
```

I defined the installed application as follow:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'datalake_backend'
    'datalake_backend.IAV',
    'datalake_backend.AMAZON_FUSE_REVENUE'
]
```

and it's falling to find datalake_backend. It this not possibile or am I missing something? Perhaps need I to defined a new application which holds the datalake_backend common logic and service? Something like:

```
 datalake_backend
    __init__.py
    models.py 
    :
    IAV_PANEL
        __init__.py
        models.py
        :
    AMAZON_FUSE_PANEL
        __init__.py
        models.py
        :
    DATALAKE_BACKEND
        __init__.py 
        models.py 
        :
```

In this case, I wonder why there is a models.py file into the project folder. Any link, suggestion or other pointers are welcomed.

Comment: Do you have `migrations` package inside datalake_backend?

Comment: try `./manage.py makemigrations datalake_backend`

Comment: No, I have not the package. I’ll try again after add it within 8h.

Comment: No way. How can I add the datalake_backend to the installed_app list? Not sure that what I'm asking makes sense, anyway I'm a Django newbie.